# Are there any tools for tracking DAO treasuries?

Tags: dao, tools

DAOs hold large amounts of capital. Are there any websites for tracking them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there are several tools that offer DAO treasury stats.

- [DeepDAO](https://deepdao.io/organizations)
- [OpenOrgs](https://openorgs.info/)
- [DeFiLlama Treasuries](https://defillama.com/treasuries)